# How To get just only the added this object when many to many table is updated

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

---

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.db.models.signals import post_save, m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver
# Create your models here.

class FollowersModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, related_name='usr')
    follow = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="whom")
    my_followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='my_followers')

    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user)

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=FollowersModel.follow.through)
def follow_by_follow_add_or_remove(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('action') == 'post_add':
        print kwargs.get('instance').follow.all()

        **solved part**
        print list(kwargs.get('pk_set'))[0]
        # then it returns the id of the added object :)))
```

In this example when I print kwargs.get('instance').follow.all() then I can get the whole lists of follow label but I just want to get only the added one, I mean I am searching kind of print kwargs.get('instance').follow.this(), just like jquery we do 'this.append()' only the added one

**Okey Bros It is Solved**

solved part is in the codes :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) of `m2m_changed` signal:

> **pk_set**
>
> For the `pre_add`, `post_add`, `pre_remove` and `post_remove` actions, this is a set of primary key values that have been added to or removed from the relation

You can access `pk_set` from the `kwargs` to check which primary keys values have been added/removed.

You can use this `pk_set` to fetch the corresponding objects from database.

Comment: I just 2 seconds ago was looking in documentation just this topic pk_set, that is destiny man :)))), Okey I will try it :))))

Comment: That's cool! Most of the times looking in the documentation is helpful if the documentation is good and maintained.

Comment: of course bro in order to get the id of the added object --> list(kwargs.get('pk_set'))[0] then it returns its id, so we are happy to go :)))

Comment: Please follow the link in the comment above to know `What should I do when someone answers my question?`